# does changing table in MySQL affect php page?

Tags: php, mysql

I have php page that will track user on log in and store the information in table named 'logins' on phpmyadmin

now the php code for that looks like this

```html
$numlogin = mysql_num_rows($get_client);
if($numlogin==1) {
 $thisid = mysql_result($get_client,0,"id");
 $thisfore = mysql_result($get_client,0,"forename");
 $thissur = mysql_result($get_client,0,"surname");
 $thiscomp = mysql_result($get_client,0,"companyname");
           
  $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
 $logdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
 $logyear = date('Y');
 $logmonth = date('m');
 $logqtr = ceil($logmonth/3);
                 
 $reslog = mysql_query("insert into logins values ('','$myid','$loginemail','$thisfore','$thissur','$thiscomp',
 '$ip','$logdate','$logyear','$logmonth','$logqtr')") or die("Error 91");
```

**but** if I want to add ipinfo to track their location then I have to add new column to table to store iplocation

What should I do?

Can I alter table on phpmyadmin and write some code to php later?
or what is the correct way to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't safely add a new column to the `logins` table with the code you've written. Your `INSERT` statement doesn't list the columns that it's inserting into, so that means you have to provide values for all the columns. If you change the table columns, the query will get an error because the number of values doesn't match the number of columns.

This is why you should always be explicit in your `INSERT` queries. Change it to:

```
$reslog = mysql_query("insert into logins (id, userid, email, forname, surname, comp, ip, logdate, logyear, logmonth, logqtr)
    values ('','$myid','$loginemail','$thisfore','$thissur','$thiscomp',
            '$ip','$logdate','$logyear','$logmonth','$logqtr')") or die("Error 91");
```

Of course, replace the column names I used with the actual column names of your table.

Once you've done this you should be able to add new columns to the table without causing the code to get an error.